# Unity Game Crashes on Startup

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, adb

I am working on a project which is going to be creating a game in Unity for Android but in the process I encountered this problem that has been bothering me for quite a bit.
The thing is that if I launch the application/game in an emulator or a more decent device it works just fine but when I try it on my phone which is "ZTE BLADE L3" it just crashes immediately after launch.
I registred some of the log (filtered by error) and I got some data that I didn't understand, it will be wonderful if one of you guys help me find out where the problem occurs.
I have tried all what Unity Docs put out in [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingAndroid.html) but nothing worked.

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
E/ctxmgr  (16988): [BaseServerTask]Failed network request due to no network connectivity:
E/ctxmgr  (16988): [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl fetch: network status=1
E/MPlugin (16988): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
E/ctxmgr  (16988): [BaseServerTask]Failed network request due to no network connectivity:
E/ctxmgr  (16988): [AccountAclCallback]Failed Acl fetch: network status=1
E/MPlugin (19785): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL](19785): disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (2/0x47/0x48/0x46)
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL](19785): disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (480/854/1)
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/Unity   (19785): [EGL] eglChooseConfig(m_EGLDisplay, configAttribs, NULL, 0, &eglConfigCount): EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE: An unrecognized attribute or attribute value was passed in the attribute list.
E/Unity   (19785): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
E/Unity   (19785): (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/egl/ConfigEGL.cpp Line: 376)
E/Unity   (19785):
E/lowmemorykiller(  138): Error opening /proc/19448/oom_score_adj; errno=2
E/InputDispatcher(  661): channel 'f626dc5 com.pfeHY.pfeGame/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
E/Launcher3(19884): MTKUnreadLoader, initUnreadNumberFromSystem SettingNotFoundException key = com_android_rcse_mtk_unread, e = com_android_rcse_mtk_unread
E/Launcher3(19884): MTKUnreadLoader, initUnreadNumberFromSystem SettingNotFoundException key = com_mediatek_cellbroadcastreceiver_mtk_unread, e = com_mediatek_cellbroadcastreceiver_mtk_unread
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL](19884): disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (2/0x47/0x48/0x46)
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL](19884): disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (480/854/1)
E/        (  228): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
E/        (  228): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
E/        (  228): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
E/        (  228): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
E/MPlugin (19956): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
E/MPlugin (19907): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
```

More informations about subject:
The application minimum API level: Android 4.4 'Kit Kat' (API lvl 19)
My device's API level: Android 5.0.2 'Lollipop' (API lvl 21)

I imported several packages of particles effects and they might have hidden plugins of some sort and maybe that's what's causing the issue. I don't know really. I am just making assumptions.

Any help would be much appreciated.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed the problem by deleting a particles package that I was using for some effects. As soon as I deleted this package, the application started normally, yet I still have some performance issues but that can be fixed with some profiling.